# Test refactor from single to bulk

Tags: unit-test

I have the method below on my test class. All I want to do is modify it to delete a group of opportunities, instead of just one (the SOQL is currently LIMIT 1). But when I fill a list instead of the single rcblopp variable, my asserts down at the bottom don't compile ("Method does not exist or incorrect signature"). Help please! Thanks in advance!

```
    //non-sysadmin can't delete single receivable
@isTest
public static void myTestMethod1(){
    User standardu = [SELECT Id from User WHERE UserName = 'standarduser@sparkprogram.org'];
    system.runAs(standardu){

        // Perform test
        Test.startTest();
        Opportunity rcblopp = [SELECT Id from Opportunity WHERE Receivable__c = true LIMIT 1];
        try {
            delete rcblopp;
        }
        catch (DMLException e)
        {
            // not expected - could assert the message here
            system.debug('Should have gotten the error message from the trigger.');
        }

        Database.DeleteResult result = Database.delete(rcblopp, false);
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assert(!result.isSuccess());
        System.assert(result.getErrors().size() > 0);
        System.assertEquals('Receivable opportunities should not be deleted. See wiki: https://sites.google.com/a/sparkprogram.org/spark-interconnected-data-systems-wiki/finance/receivable-opportunities Receivable opportunities can only be deleted by a system administrator.',
                            result.getErrors()[0].getMessage());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to deal with the lists all the way down:

```
Database.DeleteResult[] results = Database.delete(rcblopp, false);
for(Database.DeleteResult[] result: results) {
  System.assert(result.isSuccess(), 'Expected deletion to be allowed');
}
```

Or, if you're still going after errors:

```
Database.DeleteResult[] results = Database.delete(rcblopp, false);
Test.stopTest();
System.assert(!results[0].isSuccess());
System.assert(results[0].getErrors().size() > 0);
System.assertEquals('Receivable opportunities should not be deleted. See wiki: https://sites.google.com/a/sparkprogram.org/spark-interconnected-data-systems-wiki/finance/receivable-opportunities Receivable opportunities can only be deleted by a system administrator.',
                    results[0].getErrors()[0].getMessage());
```